# Insert failing when populating boolean field with dynamic apex

Tags: custom-metadata, dynamic-apex

We have a product configurator app that converts OpportunityLineItems to QuoteLineItems. We implemented a new solution with custom metadata relationships to dynamically map field values between the 2 objects without having to update the code every time a new field is added.

We are running into a problem with a boolean field on insert where the value is null/not set.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD, 24x7 Subscription Support: value not of required type: : [X24x7_Subscription_Support__c]

I have confirmed that the field exists on both objects and is of the same type.

I have read that by [using sObject.get(field)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/131136/17894) should automatically cast null values to false. However, we are doing this and it is still failing.

This is the simplified version of the code that converts the line items:

```
//metadata queried here in a different method
Set<String> dynamicFields = new Set<String>();
for (Configurator_Field__mdt field : [SELECT Id, Destination_Field__r.QualifiedApiName FROM Configurator_Field__mdt]) {
    dynamicFields.add(field.Destination_Field__r.QualifiedApiName);
}

//metadata fields are passed to a method that does the conversion
//note the use of SObject.get()
public static QuoteLineItem CreateQLIFromOLI(OpportunityLineItem oli, Set<String> dynamicFields)
{
    QuoteLineItem qli = new QuoteLineItem();
    for (String field : dynamicFields) {
        qli.put(field, oli.get(field));
    }

    return qli;
}
//insertion happens after the quote line item is returned
insert qli;
```

Can someone recommend a way to handle null boolean fields while avoiding hardcoded field mapping?

Comment: I believe i misread the linked link. `Sobject.get(field)` should be used when you WANT the null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid setting null values in this case:

```
for (String field : dynamicFields) {
    Object value = oli.get(field);
    if(value != null) {
        qli.put(field, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: simple and elegant!

Answer (score 0):

The get() method returns an Object type, it doesn't return the actual type of the field value, i.e boolean, string, date.

You can add a "Boolean" field on the metadata type to determine that that specific field is a boolean, and then do the following:

```
if fieldIsBoolean and oli.get(field) == null{
    Boolean fieldValue = (Boolean) oli.get(field)
    qli.put(field,fieldValue)
```

Comment: That code is not valid Apex.

Comment: It's called pseudo code